# What does "RUN apk add --no-cache tree" mean in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I came across the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM registry

# I am not clear what this is.
# I do not understand the following comment either.
# tree is helpful to peruse filesystem storage of images
RUN apk add --no-cache tree
```

For `apk add` I got the following three so links.

1. [How can I install Docker inside an alpine container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099218/how-can-i-install-docker-inside-an-alpine-container)
2. [Running "apk add" command in a docker container with arguments [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471471/running-apk-add-command-in-a-docker-container-with-arguments)
3. [rhat8 equivalent of "apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347929/rhat8-equivalent-of-apk-add-no-cache-gcc-musl-dev-linux-headers)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868193/1977871) from the first link says "running docker inside alpine"

Can somebody enlighten me please. Why do we want to run docker inside a docker container?

What is this `apk add`?

Comment: Valid question. I don't understand the downvotes. This Q&A helped me to realize that apk is the default package manager for alpine linux which is used heavily in docker base layers.

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as accepted

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`apk` is the package manager used in alpine. The command installs the `tree` package in the image.

Additionally the `--no-cache` flag, doesn't add anything to cache, so you wouldn't need to run `rm /var/cache/apk/*` later (which is a good practice)